# Golang: Type [type] is not an expression; json config parsing

Tags: json, go, struct, compiler-errors

I'm trying to work out a bit of code to pull in config from a JSON file.
When I attempt to build, I get this error

```
type ConfigVars is not an expression
```

Below is the config and program code I'm trying to work with. Every example I've found so far is similar to the below code. Any suggestion of what I'm doing incorrectly?

```
-- Config File
{"beaconUrl":"http://test.com/?id=1"}

-- Program Code
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "os"
)


type ConfigVars struct {
    BeaconUrl   string
}


func main() {
    configFile, err := os.Open("config.json")
    defer configFile.Close()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Opening config file", err.Error())
    }

    jsonParser := json.NewDecoder(configFile)
    if err = jsonParser.Decode(&ConfigVars); err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Parsing config file", err.Error())
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you're doing there is trying to pass a pointer to the `ConfigVars` type (which obviously doesn't really mean anything). What you want to do is make a variable whose type is `ConfigVars` and pass a pointer to that instead:

```
var cfg ConfigVars
err = jsonParser.Decode(&cfg)
...
```

Comment: Just to elaborate a bit more, the `Decode` method in your `jsonParser` object is expecting a pointer (memory address) of the `ConfigVars` instance to write output to. `ConfigVars` is a type, meaning it will only be allocated a memory address once an instance of it is created by means of a variable definition. i.e. `var cfg ConfigVars`

Answer (score 0):

For others who come onto this problem, you may find that you've forgotten to initialize the variable during assignment using the `:=` operator, as described in [Point 3 at the end of this GoLang tutorial](https://go.dev/doc/tutorial/create-module).

```golang
var cfg ConfigVars
err := jsonParser.Decode(&cfg)
```